# Mutation-testing generation

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-automation-framework, unit-tests, test-strategy

I'm giving a presentation about this paper: https://www.st.cs.uni-saarland.de/publications/files/fraser-tse-2011.pdf
Unfortunately I don't understand 2 things:

1. On **page 9** table 1: Where are these mutants from? This table summarizes classes of the example projects and it's about to automatically generate mutants. But why there already are mutants listed in this table?
2. On **page 10** there are 2 figures (6 and 7): I don't really understand what they illustrate.

Comment: I voted to close the question. As it is worded now, and it can be of hardly any use to anyone else in the community. A better way would be to isolating a particular SQA problem, make it more generic or better described.

Comment: In the bottom of the first page there is author contact info. I believe you get much more help from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rectangle is called box plot. For more details see wikipedia.